# Trying to make the command lines start plotting from the position zero with a vector as argument

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to do a task, where I have to compare the histogram of a sample with poisson distribution of size 100, with the expected frequencies that they should have, so I did this.

```
prob0 = dpois(0, 2.5)
prob1 = dpois(1, 2.5)
prob2 = dpois(2, 2.5)
prob3 = dpois(3, 2.5)
prob4 = dpois(4, 2.5)
prob5 = dpois(5, 2.5)
prob6 = dpois(6, 2.5)
prob7 = dpois(7, 2.5)
prob8 = dpois(8, 2.5)
prob9 = dpois(9, 2.5)

n100 = rpois(100, 2.5)
hist(n100)
y <- c(rep(prob0 * 100), rep(prob1 * 100), rep(prob2 * 100), rep(prob3 * 100), rep(prob4 * 100), rep(prob5 * 100), rep(prob6 * 100), rep(prob7 * 100), rep(prob8 * 100), rep(prob9 * 100))
lines(y, col="blue")
```

Resulting in:

[image]

**The problem I have is that by using the command line with a vector as an argument, it begins to plot the line from position 1, I guess it's because R indexes start from number 1, but I need it to begins to plot from the position 0, what I can do?**

To fix it I thought I could make the vector's index start from 0, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the x to the plot

```
lines(1 : length(y) - 1, y, col="blue")
```